# Creating a script that 'restarts' usb devices

Tags: usb, hard-disk, devices, crash

I'm using my RasPi as a media center with the media stored on an external HDD. Now the problem is that the HDD crashes sometimes, usually one or a few times a week. When this happens the drive is 'disconnected', and so my system cannot download after these events.

Can I create a script that sort of forces a restart of all the usb devices (so no reboot of the Pi) when (using udev) the HDD crashes?

Comment: It would be more interesting trying to investigate why it crashes. I used to have a banana pi that crashed bi-weekly and I managed to track it down that to a faulty *realtek* wifi chipset. Failing that, I would recommend a watchdog that reboots it, as the system can be left on a inconsistent state.

Comment: How should I investigate this?

Comment: logs for starters

Comment: Where can I find those logs?